# Turning complex XML (or content tree) into HTML - How to do it (in Java)?

Tags: java, web-development, html, xml, xslt

I have a deep object content tree that I transform into a XML using JAXB and a small self written API on top.

But now I want to create a static HTML site that has basically the same content (and structure) as the XML, but with tables, parts that can be collapsed, images and so on.

How can I approach this?

- Using **XSLT** seems a bit "redundant" since it depends heavily on the XML and if the XML changes the XSLT will have to change as well.
- Some kind of **template engine** is over the top because I only need one static site.
- Building the HTML with a **simple library like j2html** hardcoding the structure and small methods for elements that are repeating.

I'm currently in favor of the last option simply because it seems the easiest and fastest way, but I'm worried that I'm shooting myself in the foot with it down the road.

Comment: The XSLT option seems to be the most flexible way for me, and is robust against later changes.

Comment: Your con against XSLT doesn't seem valid.  All the proposed solutions will need to change if the source XML changes.

Comment: XSLT would seem to have been designed for almost exactly this sort of problem.

Comment: FWIW: the OP posted (originally as an answer, which will become deleted soon) they finally used  the j2htlm solution. That's IMHO fine; though XSLT was probably designed for such tasks, for a team where everybody is fluent in Java but not equally knowing XSLT, a Java library based solution is probably easier to handle. There is more than "one way" to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> But now I want to create a static HTML site that has basically the same content (and structure) as the XML, but with tables, parts that can be collapsed, images and so on.

This seems like a basic use case for HTML, CSS stylesheets, and maybe some Javascript. Tables are basic HTML (and are so old that many people regard them as being obsolete), collapsing parts can be done with CSS and/or Javascript, and images are also basic HTML. If all you want is a web page just... make a web page?

If you want to automate turning the XML into HTML, googling "XML to HTML" turns up multiple options on the first page. Pick whichever one works for your use-case.